# How to make a function to subsetting a data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a newbie with pandas. I have a df that contains demographics for each sate. I am trying to create a function that takes the df and list of rows, in this case a list of States, and return a df for each state. I think my logic is off because I am getting an error. Thanks in advance.

This is an example of my df:

```
     State   Year   Deaths          
0   Alabama 1999    39  
1   Alabama 2000    46  
2   Alabama 2001    67  
3   Alabama 2002    75
```

Sharing the function I tried below:

```
def subseting(df ,list_of_states):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    for i in list_of_states:
         if i == df_copy.State :
                df_copy = df[df.State == i]
                df_copy = df_copy[[ 'Year' , 'Deaths']]
    return df_copy

a = ['Alabama' , 'Alaska' , 'Arizona ']

print(subseting(df, a))
```

Sharing my error below:

```
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-304-3528e6a59ccf> in <module>
      1 a = ['Alabama' , 'Alaska' , 'Arizona ']
      2 
----> 3 print(subseting_44(df, a))

<ipython-input-303-faa8c8e91e86> in subseting_44(df, list_of)
      2     df_copy = df.copy()
      3     for i in list_of:
----> 4         if i == df.State:
      5 #     df_copy= df[df.State == list_of]
      6 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1477                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1478                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1479 
   1480     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `isin`: `df[df['State'].isin(a)]`

Comment: I think you did a good excecise with the loops, but @busybear suggestion is correct, you are looking for `isin`

Comment: Thanks for the subjections but when I tried ```isin``` it gives me this error ```TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the  pandas `query` to filter and `groupby` to create separate subsets

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(
"""i   State   Year   Deaths          
0   Alabama 1999    39  
1   Alabama 2000    46  
2   Alabama 2001    67  
3   Alabama 2002    75  
4   Alaska  2001     1
5   Alaska  2002     2   
6   Maine   2002     3   
7   Maine   2002     5   
"""
))

# single filtered dataframe
def subsetting1(df, list_of_states):
   return df.query('State in @list_of_states')

print (subsetting1(df, ["Alaska", "Alabama"]))

# list of dataframes
def subsetting2(df, list_of_states):
    grouped = df.query('State in @list_of_states').groupby("State")
    return [grouped.get_group(d) for d in list_of_states]

subsets = subsetting2(df, ["Alaska", "Alabama"])
for s in subsets:
    print(s)
```

prints

```
       i    State  Year  Deaths
    0  0  Alabama  1999      39
    1  1  Alabama  2000      46
    2  2  Alabama  2001      67
    3  3  Alabama  2002      75
    4  4   Alaska  2001       1
    5  5   Alaska  2002       2
```

and

```
       i   State  Year  Deaths
    4  4  Alaska  2001       1
    5  5  Alaska  2002       2

       i    State  Year  Deaths
    0  0  Alabama  1999      39
    1  1  Alabama  2000      46
    2  2  Alabama  2001      67
    3  3  Alabama  2002      75
```